# Как лучше организовать данные при создании иерархии категорий?

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть классы `Animal`,`Type_of_Animals`,`Place_of_life`.

Класс `Type_of_Animals` содержит вектор объектов `Animal`. А класс  `Place_of_life`, в свою очередь, содержит вектор объектов `Type_of_Animals`.

К примеру, таких животных как муха,комар,овод и тд. можно отнести к типу насекомые(т.е. юзаем объект класса `Type_of_Animals`). Эти животные принадлежат к сухопутному виду(юзаем класс `Place_of_life`). Выбрал эту иерархию из мыслей о том как должны представляться эти объекты для пользователя. Или лучше будет создать класс `Animal`, в котором будут добавлены два поля: тип и место жизни? Усложнит ли это задачу поиска заданного животного/категории и отображения категорий в приложении?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем корректно задан вопрос, но попробую ответить.
Нельзя спроектировать структуру иерархии классов, не зная, что будет делать программа в целом.
В вашем подходе есть один очевидный минус, при создании зверушки Вам нужно будет пихать ее в объекты классов `Type_of_Animals` и `Place_of_Life`. Т.е., либо конструктор зверушки будет заниматься совершенно не своим делом, модифицируя совершенно посторонние объекты (что идеологически неправильно), либо создав очередную зверушку, Вам (или пользователю) нужно будет обязательно сразу пихать ее в другие объекты.

Вообще, задача, представляется классической для иерархии наследования классов:
Базовый класс `Animal` из которого насдедуются `EarthAnimal` и `OceanAnimals` из которых наследуются `Insect`, `Fish`, `Whale`, из `Fish` в свою очередь `Shark` и т.п. Какие-то из ступеней иерархии (вплоть до всех, в принципе) можно засунуть в перечисления в самом базовом классе:

```
class Animal {
public:
    enum PlaceOfLife { earth, ocean }
    enum Class { fish, whale, insect, mlekopitayushiy }
private:
    PlaceOfLife place_of_life;
    Class animal_class;
}
```

(не знаю, как млекопитающее по английски, сорри)
Но если основной задачей программы будет быстро вывести всех сухопутных, или всех насекомых (и при этом никогда или очень редко модифицировать или что-то делать с каким-то конкретным животным), то Ваш подход может быть проще и эффективнее.

Comment: так и есть, нужно будет выводить животных по определенным категориям либо группам.